# Error when trying to filter OData on a decimal field

Tags: odata, decimal, filtering

I have this snippet of code

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    params: params,
    timeout: timeout || deferred.promise
})
```

In `params` I have a `$filter` property.  In the dataset I am filtering I have a decimal property called `foo`.  If I set `$filter` to

```
"foo eq 100"
```

I get the correct results: all results where foo is equal to 100.

If I set `$filter` to

```
"foo eq 100.5"
```

I get an error.  The message is

```
"The query specified in the URI is not valid. A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Decimal' and 'Edm.Double' for operator kind 'Equal'"
```

How can I do decimal filtering?

Comment: Can you post a Plunker of this? At first it looked like a problem parsing your `filter` expression, but I think this is more specific to where are how you are doing the `$filter`, which I don't quite understand

Comment: Where is this error appearing? And what is this `"foo eq 100"` syntax - I've never seen it

Comment: Did you try `"foo eq '100.5'"`?

Comment: It would seem that this question has nothing to do with JavaScript or AngularJS. This question is about an OData service, so tell us about that, not your JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with JavaScript or AngularJS.

You are querying an OData service where it appears that `foo` is an `Edm.Decimal` value, but you are trying to compare it against `100.5`, which is an `Edm.Double` literal. The `eq` operator does not support comparing an `Edm.Decimal` to an `Edm.Double`.

To remedy this, use an `Edm.Decimal` literal:

```
 "foo eq 100.5M"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a `$filter` param to an `$http` call, so I don't quite follow what you're doing. However, if you just want to filter the result, you can do that with a strict comparison via the built in `filter` `$filter` ([Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter))

Check out this Plunker for an example of how to filter a `ng-repeat` expression in your template: [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wnd0yaE9mUtyzv25IL9d?p=preview)

Code:

```
<h2>Filter</h2>
Value: <input type="number" ng-model="value">
<hr/>
<h2>Items</h2>
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:value:true">
  {{item.value}}
</div>
```